# Count Error Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Problem :**

I think that I am missing something stupid or anything but the problem is that my `COUNT()` function returns a value even if the cell is empty.

**Screenshots:**

[SheetA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7VJI.png) contains the reference table for `COUNT`

[SheetB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0uh5.png) contains the `COUNT` value from `SheetA`

**Formula:**

```
=COUNTIF('SheetA'!M223:Q325, "1")
```

But as you can see, it returns `39`. Even if the cells are empty.

**What I tried:**

Cleared contents

Cleared formatting

Any ideas?

**EDIT :** solved, there are hidden rows. :(

Comment: Try COUNTA instead of COUNT

Comment: If the rows are hidden by a filter use `=SUBTOTAL(2,'SheetA'!M223:Q325)`.  This will perform a count, but ignore filtered values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cells are not empty, you have many hidden rows there. 
Unhide the rows and see the 39 values there.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in filter function.
As your image, sheet A filtering so maybe have 39 value "1" in hidden row